# How to append values to a dictionary after a firebase query?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

In the below code I am trying to append string uids to a dictionary the problem is when I do so it seems like the dict is reset after each iteration. How can I fix this?

```
    func getFollowing() {
    self.ref.child("Following").child(uid)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String:[String : Any]] {
                for key in data.keys {
                    var dict = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).usersCurrentUserIsFollowing
                    dict[key] = true
                    print(dict, " this is gtteh dict now dhfsakflk")
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by doing the following:

```
    func getFollowing() {
    self.ref.child("Following").child(uid)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var usersData = ["":true]
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String:[String : Any]] {
                for key in data.keys {
                    usersData[key] = true
                }
                var dict = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).usersCurrentUserIsFollowing
                dict = usersData
            }
        })
}
```